# Sqlalchemy mass deletion orm creation

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How to write the express the following queries in sqlalchemy orm ?

```
DELETE FROM ACCESS_STRING_DETAILS WHERE MENU_ID IN(SELECT MENU_ID FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM TIME_DETAILS WHERE MENU_ID IN(SELECT MENU_ID FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM REDIRECTOR_INPUT_PARAMS WHERE COMMAND_ID IN(SELECT KEYWORD FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM REDIRECTOR_COMMANDS WHERE COMMAND_ID IN(SELECT KEYWORD FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM RANGE_DETAILS WHERE COMMAND_ID IN(SELECT KEYWORD FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM CLIENT_RSP_DETAILS WHERE KEYWORD IN(SELECT KEYWORD FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122)
DELETE FROM REDIRECTOR WHERE SERVICE=122
```

What i basically need is to delete all the records from table which matches `MENU_ID` and `KEYWORD` for a particular `SERVICE` in `REDIRECTOR`  table

Comment: Do you already have the tables modeled in SQLAlchemy metadata?

Comment: @MartijnPieters :  Yes the tables are modeled , i donno what is the equvalent of IN statement in sqlalchemy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the filter on `SERVICE=122` separately first; I am assuming you have models for all the tables that match the table name, using camelcase.

The menu_id and keyword selects are also stored for reuse:

```
service_filter = Redirector.service == 122
menu_id_select = session.query(Redirector.menu_id).filter(service_filter)
keyword_select = session.query(Redirector.keyword).filter(service_filter)
```

Now you can apply these selects for all your deletion queries:

```
(session
    .query(AccessStringDetails)
    .filter(AccessStringDetails.menu_id.in_(menu_id_select))
    .delete(False))
(session
    .query(TimeDetails)
    .filter(TimeDetails.menu_id.in_(menu_id_select))
    .delete(False))
(session
    .query(RedirectorInputParams)
    .filter(RedirectorInputParams.command_id.in_(keyword_select))
    .delete(False))
# etc.

session.query(Redirector).filter(service_filter).delete(False)
```

These examples are using the [`Column.in_` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.in_) with the select statements, turning the latter into subselects, to produce queries like:

```
DELETE FROM access_string_details WHERE access_string_details.menu_id IN (SELECT redirector.menu_id AS redirector_menu_id 
FROM redirector 
WHERE redirector.service = :service_1)
```

with the `:service_1` parameter set to `122`.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters : delete(False) , y this false is passed to delete ?

Comment: @AkhilThayyil: See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete; `False` means no cleaning up of the session object cache. Other options are `'fetch'` and `'evaluate'`. Only needed if any of the deleted objects might be cached in the session and you need to do more in this transaction after the deletion.